# Queue Consumers have pending messages but they are not getting processed

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I am using the combination of activemq, camel and spring. For queues, we have multiple consumers on them; On some queue consumers, we see that there are pending messages (goes upto 100 which is same as prefetch) and they are not getting processed at all but other consumers for the same queue, it is business as usual.

I looked into deeper to understand what's happening and found that spring cachingconnectionfactory could be causing this issue - we are suspecting that this caching connection factory could be making some clients as inactive and messages left in their prefetch buffer are not getting processed. Are we right in our findings?

Apart from this, is there any way we can get the messages from the prefetch buffer released from the inactive consumers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use a `CachingConnectionFactory` with variable concurrency, or you must disable caching of consumers; see the javadocs for `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

```
 * <p><b>Note: Don't use Spring's {@link org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory}
 * in combination with dynamic scaling.</b> Ideally, don't use it with a message
 * listener container at all, since it is generally preferable to let the
 * listener container itself handle appropriate caching within its lifecycle.
```

Otherwise idle consumers will be put in the cache.

Comment: Thanks, that's our findings too. Is there a way to retrieve the messages stuck at inactive consumers?

Comment: No; unless the volume increases again and the consumers are checked out of the cache.